# How to control other View in different Activity?

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I have created the customAdapter of `ListView`. when I click the `Button` in the `ListView`,I want to control the `TextView` outside the `ListView` from different layout. Notice ! There are not in the same Java code.

here is what I want to do:

```
        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            TextView tx=(TextView) txt.findViewById(R.id.moneytext);
              //find the textview outside listview (now In the same java code and xml)

            totalmoney= (Integer.parseInt(tx.getText().toString()))+(Integer.parseInt(price[position])); 
             //get the textview integer and add to my present number

            tx.setText(""+totalmoney);
             //post on the textview

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you write on a white board of a classroom from another classroom? No.

Comment: @JoelFernandes yes he can

Comment: @Maurice Liao May I ask this for sure the `TextView` and `ListView` are in same Activity ?

Comment: so any connent can be established?  No? I just set the Listadapter tho. Both of them shows in the same page of app

Comment: Okey I'll answer.

Comment: @Yasin Kacmaz    Yes they are in the same activity  i go capture it  wait for a while

Comment: I cannot post the image yet....................... by Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

There is couple ways to do that I remember 3 of :

1) Add `TextView` to your `ListView` adapter constructor's parameters

2) Add your `Activity` to constructor

3) Use Event based solution like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)  [This can be used even your `TextView` and `ListView` in different Activity and you don't need parameters]

There is example of 1 and 2:

```
public class YourListAdapter{

TextView strangerTextView;
YourActivity yourActivity;

public YourListAdapter(TextView strangerTextView,Activity yourActivity){
   //using one of them is enough
   this.strangerTextView=strangerTextView;
   this.yourActivity=yourActivity;
}
//when changing text use like 

strangerTextView.setText("Class Board");

//or (make sure you have global public textview attribute in your YourActivity class)

yourActivity.textview.setText("Class Board");


}
```

For `EventBus` :

1) Create a class that holds event information :

```
public class TextChangeEvent{
    public String newtext;
    public TextChangeEvent(String newtext){
        this.newtext=newtext;
    }
}
```

2) Then in your relevant Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this))EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);

}

@Subscribe
public void onEvent(TextChangeEvent event) {
    this.textView.setText(event.newtext)
}
```

3) Post events like that, anywhere you want :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new TextChangeEvent("newtext"));
```

Comment: Finally I put them in same.java solve the problem THx for your eventbus

Comment: I didn't said put them same class but never mind, glad to fix.

Comment: XDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD  learn eventbus takes a bit of time. I am kind of rush now

Comment: @MauriceLiao I didn't know about you going for EventBus. I edited my answer for a quick setup of EventBus

Answer (score -2):

Are your TextView in the same activity? If yes, then you should put

```
tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moneytext);
```

in onCreate() method and then access it from listener you have:

```
tx.setText("" + totalmoney);
```

If it is not in the same activity, you can make something like this:

```
public class ClassA extends Activity
{
    public TextView textView;

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moneytext);
    }
}

public class ClassB extends Activity
{
    ...
        viewHolder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //classA is a global variable that you get for example from contructor
        tx = classA.textView;

        totalmoney= (Integer.parseInt(tx.getText().toString()))+(Integer.parseInt(price[position])); 
         //get the textview integer and add to my present number

        tx.setText(""+totalmoney);
         //post on the textview

    }
});
    ...
}
```

Comment: i set a adapter the make the customlistview and the Textview in the Same Activity. There is a redline under "super.onCreate();"